# WordPress: What plugin(s) for job form tracking/management system?

Tags: ajax, forms, wordpress, infopath

Our construction consulting company currently uses an InfoPath/SharePoint job tracking/management system. We want to create a job form tracking platform for use on our site's WordPress backend, *and I'm wondering what WordPress plugin(s) can offer this functionality*.

All details regarding a job are entered into a form with various subsections, such as "Job Information" and "Architect Details." The platform needs to consist of two primary areas:

1. A form to enter relevant job details (preferably AJAX-based)
2. A directory to manage and track the jobs

Can someone point me in the direction of which plugins would be my best options?

To give you an idea of what we're looking for, our current system looks like this:

[image: Infopath/Sharepoint job tracking:]

Comment: I dont think there is a Project management plugin out there. This looks like custom work, will need to hire a developer!

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), a very powerful and versatile AJAX-based contact form plugin, in conjunction with [Contact Form DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) which stores all contact form submissions in the database and basically allows you to view the database table that contains all the submissions.

Of course this isn't going to be very elegant if you don't have a developer to style it up (especially on the backend), but it will work functionally.

You could also look into integrating your form / contact form with a CRM like SalesForce, but again that will require some developer time.

Answer (score 0):

[Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) is pretty powerful to. But what @ennui states, probably some custom work.